# IFS formula not returning correct values

Tags: excel-formula, ifs

```
=IFS(F38=1,"Not Satisfactory",F38>=1.5,"In Progress",F38>=2.5,"Good",F38>=3.5,"Very Good",F38>=4.5,"Excellent")
```

The formula returns correct values for "Not Satisfactory" and for "In Progress"; I can´t understand why for the remaining 3 (Good, Very Good and Excellent) it doesn´t work.

Comment: Which value does the cell F38 have?

Comment: For example, if F38 has a value of `3`, it satisfies `F38>=1.5`, therefore it will return `"In Progress"`. It won't check whether it matches "Good" etc. Also, your code returns `#N/A` if the input is `1.2` (not sure if that's what you want, though)

Comment: So its always a number format in that cell right, have you tried to change the format there?

Comment: You can put the condition starting from 'Excellent'. Or you can change the checking to use '<' and change the numbers as well.

Answer (score 1):

What is happening is that the formula is going through your arguments one by one until one is true. That means that as soon as a number is above 1.5, the second argument is true and it doesn't have to proceed.
I suggest you swap your arguments around and start with the biggest number, that helped for me.

Like so:

```
=IFS(F38>=4.5,"Excellent",F38>=3.5,"Very Good",F38>=2.5,"Good",F38>=1.5,"In Progress",F38=1,"Not Satisfactory")
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned in the comments that the cell provides a number format, you can try the `ROUND` function to get the nearest integer before you start using your specific formula.

Your code then could look like this:

```
=IFS(ROUND(F38,0)=1,"Not Satisfactory",ROUND(F38,0)>=2,"In Progress",ROUND(F38,0)>=3,"Good",ROUND(F38,0)>=4,"Very Good",ROUND(F38,0)>=5,"Excellent")
```

Comment: For an input of "4.5", the current code results in "In Progress", but OP probably wants it to be "Excellent"

Comment: @Avallon if you are satisfied with my answer you can accept it :)

Comment: @qrsngky that is true thanks for pointing out! Since Avallon is satisfied i guess thats fine, but otherwise the current formula would look like this `=IFS(ROUND(F38,0)=1,"Not Satisfactory",ROUND(F38,0)>=1.5,"In Progress",ROUND(F38,0)>=2.5,"Good",ROUND(F38,0)>=3.5,"Very Good",ROUND(F38,0)>=4.5,"Excellent")`